# How can I make white diagonal lines across my image?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, effects

Could you please tell me how could I make such effect with photoshop, please?

This is without effect:

[image]

and this is with the effect:

[image]

I want to know how can I make this effect of lines. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

These are called scanlines.

- Open up a new file, 3px*3px, with transparent background.
- Paint a white pixel line from the bottom left to top right.
- Edit > Save as pattern.
- Open your file and open the layer settings of the layer you want to apply the scanlines to.
- Activate pattern overlay and choose the pattern you just saved.
- Set layer style to the opacity you want.

Comment: To reproduce those exact lines you'd create a 3x3px image and fill all but the top left and bottom right, and reduce the opacity.. but yeh.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell because the attached photos are showing different content, but I think it’s just an overlay.

So all you have to do is find (or create) such a pattern and lay it on top of your image with an opacity of 10–20%.

Answer (score 0):

Go to [THIS](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi1_6HLtsnOAhXFLSYKHceACeQQjRwIBw&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.xmple.com%2Fwallpaper%2Fwhite-lines-stripes-streaks-grey-540x960-c2-ffffff-dcdcdc-l2-54-108-a-30-f-1-image%2F&psig=AFQjCNFsGfCkKJEB1EtoKwlh7xg051YoAA&ust=1471556848123647) image, scroll down to choose the smallest size larger than your image, remove the grey so you just have the white, overlay it on your image in a new layer, and then lower the opacity of the layer to taste.

Note: you can use any image like this, I just am giving you the one I found. If this is for commercial reasons you should check for authorization.